Can unit prefixes be interpreted as algebraic stand-ins?
I am currently a little confused about whether unit prefixes can be interpreted algebraically
For example:
$$4km = 4\times 10^{3} m$$
Is it incorrect to say that $k$ is simply an algebraic stand in for $10^{3}$, or when dealing with units should you only consider the unit and its prefix together?
For example:
$$(4km)^{2} = 16km^{2}$$
But not:
$$=16k^{2}m^{2}$$
Which would be true if the $k$ was simply an algebraic stand in for $10^{3}$, but this actually makes more intuitive sense to me anyway?
Please can someone shed some more light on this, are there any particular reasons for why prefixes are treated the way that they are?

Have you ever seen an area measurement with units $k^2m^2$?

No, but I don't see why it wouldn't work?

It would work. We just don’t do it that way. There’s nothing deep going on. A standalone $k$ would probably be interpreted as the Boltzmann constant, since often people don’t bother to write $k_B$.

I'll try to explain my confusion a little clearly. When I'm doing problems, in my head, I view the $k$ or $M$ or whatever is in front of the unit, as a number like $10^{3}$ or $10^{6}$, but $(km)^{2}$ is equal to $km^{2}$ not $k^{2}m^{2}$, which makes me think that the way I view the $k$ or $M$ as a number, is a poor way of thinking about units? Maybe I am overthinking this, but it just irritates me a bit.

It doesn't matter how you organise your mental arithmetic, as long as you get that $(4 , \rm{km})^2$ is $16$ million square metres. ;) The notation convention may be a bit irritating, but IMHO it would be more irritating if we had to write indices on the prefixes, and potentially more confusing if we wrote $\color{red}{ (4 , \rm{km})^{2} = 16 , \rm{Mm^2}}$

There is nothing “deep” going on here. This is just the result of a decision by the BIPM on the usage of the SI units.
See section 3 of the current edition of the SI Brochure
https://www.nist.gov/pml/special-publication-330

Prefix symbols … are attached to unit symbols without a space between the prefix symbol and the unit symbol. … The grouping formed by a prefix symbol attached to a unit symbol constitutes a new inseparable unit symbol … that can be raised to a positive or negative power

That is the way it works because that is the way the BIPM committee decided it should work. They give as an example:
$\mathrm{ 2.3 \ cm^3 = 2.3\ (cm)^3 = 2.3 \ (10^{-2} \ m)^3 = 2.3 \times 10^{-6}\ m^3}$
So number-wise what you want to do would work. But according to the rules of how the SI work you simply never separate the prefix from the unit. The prefix and the unit together form a single symbol representing a different unit from the base unit.
Note that last point. The symbol $\mathrm{km}$ refers to one kilometer. The kilometer is a unit. There exists a simple conversion between kilometers and meters. But a kilometer, in principle, is a separate unit that is equal in length to $1000$ meters, rather than being just a count of $1000$ meters.

Thanks! This cleared my misunderstanding really well
